# php json_encode & jquery parseJSON single quote issue

Tags: php, jquery

I searched and read most of the related topics, but they weren't what I was looking for.

I've a JSON enocded string with `json_encode` PHP function:

```
{"casts":["Matthew Modine","Adam Baldwin","Vincent D'Onofrio"],"year":1987}
```

I'm working with jQuery to put the values in appropriate fields too, in the case of testing I did the below:

```
<script>
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('<?=$data?>');
console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Suppose that $data is this:

```
$data =
<<<END
{"casts":["Matthew Modine","Adam Baldwin","Vincent D'Onofrio"],"year":1987}
END;
```

What Google chrome console produces in this case:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

However when I make a change in JSON encoded string - adding **Backslash** to single quote :

```
{"casts":["Matthew Modine","Adam Baldwin","Vincent D\'Onofrio"],"year":1987}
```

Console output is as normal:

```
Object {casts: Array[3], year: 1987}
casts: Array[3]
year: 1987
```

The question: is this error in console expected? I think escaping or replacing `'` with `\'` will be so dirty!

***UPDATED***

*Actually **$data** value comes from a `json_encode($var)` and $var is an array!*

```
$data = json_encode($var);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> However when I make a change in JSON encoded string - adding Backslash to single quote

That escapes it in the PHP string literal. It is then inserted into the PHP string as a simple `'`.

If you want to escape it before inserting it into JavaScript then you need to add slashes to the string you get *out* of `json_encode` (or rather, since you aren't using that (you should be!) the JSON string you build by hand).

That is more work then you need though.  The real solution is to remember that JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax:

```
var obj = <?=$data?>;
```

Comment: +1 no need to parse it - the output of `json_encode` is already valid JavaScript.

Comment: It would be good to specify `JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP` though. At least the former may be necessary to satisfy the [restrictions for contents of `script` elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements), and both are necessary if the document could be parsed as XML.

Comment: Hi there - a little late to the party but I had the exact same issue and this was the fix! Could you please exlain in more detail what `<?=$data ?>` means? Is that some short hand version of writing out '<?php echo $data; ?>` or is that something different?

Comment: @user1775598 You're exactly right: `<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo `

Answer (score 93):

For the broader problem of passing a JSON-encoded string in PHP (e.g., through cURL), using the JSON_HEX_APOS option is the cleanest way to solve this problem. This would solve your problem as well, although the previous answers are correct that you don't **need** to call parseJSON, and the JavaScript object is the same without calling parseJSON on `$data`.

For your code, you would just make this change:

`json_encode($var)` to `json_encode($var, JSON_HEX_APOS)`.

Here's an example of the correctly encoded data being parsed by jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/SuttX/

For further reading, here's an example from the [PHP.net json_encode manual entry](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Example #2:

```
$a = array('<foo>',"'bar'",'"baz"','&blong&', "\xc3\xa9");

echo "Apos: ",    json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_APOS), "\n";
```

This will output:

```
Apos: ["<foo>","\u0027bar\u0027","\"baz\"","&blong&","\u00e9"]
```

A full list of JSON constants can be found here: [PHP.net JSON constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: This works perfectly. For people who use twig then the code is json_encode(constant('JSON_HEX_APOS')). Thank you for this solution.

Comment: Great Answer that helped me too

Answer (score 6):

The issue you are facing is that you are presenting the results of the `json_encode` call to JavaScript as a string whereas it is valid JavaScript. Remove the `jQuery.jsonParse` set out of the output and simply assign the echoed results to the JavaScript variable in question.

```
var obj = <?= json_encode(array("casts"=>array(
    "Matthew Modine","Adam Baldwin","Vincent D'Onofrio"
),"year"=>1987)); ?>;
```

Comment: The code above will work for you... it also shows by passing the javascript parseJson step.

Answer (score 6):

This should be straightforward if the issue is about single quote only:

```
str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

check out its really help me

```
$products_arr=array();
$products_arr["category"]=array();
 while ($row = $cats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $product_item=array(
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "title" => json_encode($row['title'])// these will help you
    );

    array_push($products_arr["category"], $product_item);
}

echo json_encode($products_arr);
```