# Convert Php array to JavaScript array exception with apostrophe

Tags: javascript, php

This code work

```
let json_data = '<?php echo json_encode(["name" => "test"]) ?>';
let data = JSON.parse(json_data);
```

Problem this code

```
let json_data = '<?php echo json_encode(["name" => "cote d'ivoire"]) ?>';
let data = JSON.parse(json_data);
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

How can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON includes a `'` character which is the same character you are using to delimit the string.

The simplest solution to this is to *treat the JSON as JavaScript* (the data format is a subset of the programming language).

```
let data = <?php echo json_encode(["name" => "cote d'ivoire"]) ?>;
```

If you really want to generate a *string* of JSON which you can then parse, then the best tool to escape the special characters in it is `json_encode` (which will also add quotes around it for you, so you don't need to do that manually).

```
let json_data = <?php echo json_encode(json_encode(["name" => "test"])); ?>;
let data = JSON.parse(json_data);
```

Comment: `["name" => "cote d'ivoire"]` that part is dynamic. I can not change it

Comment: @Davit — Both my solutions will work no matter how dynamic that part is.

Comment: @Davit, Quentin [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17926404/1020526) this 5yrs ago but the solution to your problem is [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18967296/1020526) there.