# Create Downloadable csv file form JSON

Tags: javascript

I am trying to creates a csv file that I can download from my webpage using some code I have found from previous questions but it I am running into problems when some of the items have single quites e.g. `today's`

The data is from a MySQL database which I call using an API, I then use some functions so convert to csv.

The code I use to get the initial data is as follows:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "api_endpoint",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$obj = json_decode($response, true);
curl_close($curl);

?>
<script>

var js_data = '<?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>';
var js_obj_data = JSON.parse(js_data);

</script>
```

The functions I am using to convert to csv are as follows:

```
function convertToCSV(objArray) {

    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
            var item = array[i][index]
            line += array[i][index];
        }

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }

    return str;
}




function exportCSVFile(items, fileTitle) {

  var headers = {
      race_id: 'race_id Model',
      meeting_date: "meeting_date",
      time: "time",
      course: "course",
      name: "name",
      back_price: "back_price",
      probability: "probability",
      qs_price: "qs_price"
  };

  if (headers) {
      items.unshift(headers);
  }


    var csv = this.convertToCSV(items);

    var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';


    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", "tissue_prices.csv");
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}



var fileTitle = 'tissue_prices';
```

The functions are then called using:

```
exportCSVFile(js_obj_data, fileTitle);
```

A sample of the `js_obj_data` is below

```
   {
    "race_id": 123456,
    "meeting_date": "11/6/2020",
    "time": "16:00",
    "course": "Gowran_Park",
    "name": "Cap D'antibes",
    "back_price": 8.4,
    "probability": 5,
    "qs_price": 20.77
  }
```

I get an `unexpected identifier` error on this line in the console. If I remove this record then it works fine?

If I remove the above record then I get an output as expected, it is the only record with a single quote in one of the fields.
If I remove all records other than that one this is the error I get:

```
js_data = '[{"race_id":940558,"meeting_date":"11\/6\/2020","time":"16:00","course":"Gowran_Park","name":"Cap D'antibes","back_price":8.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625,"probability":5,"qs_price":20.769999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125}]
```

It's strange how the values are so long since I load them into my database with 2 decimals and I also use `decimal(8,2)` as the data type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you do this `var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);`, but then the first thing you do in `convertToCSV` is `JSON.parse(objArray)`.

Comment: _I get an unexpected identifier error on this line in the console._ it's not clear which line you are referring to here?

Comment: Seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/eLzy6tpr/

Comment: CSV is a terrible format exactly because of the handling of quotes. I strongly recommend using a good library to generate your CSV for you instead of writing your own. If you do want to write your own, find a decent CSV spec that specifies how to handle all those exceptions.

Comment: @MattBurland The unexpected error highlights that perticular block, if I remove it then I do get an output (minus the header?) so I am assuming its the `Cap D'antibes` that is causing me a problem?
Also I am not an expert in JavaScript so please excuse any mistakes, I am trying to learn as I go along

Comment: @mcv do you have any libraries you can recommend, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if one already exists.

Comment: The code you have works fine in the fiddle I posted earlier. It downloads a CSV file just fine and it opens in excel without any problems. So your problem exists somewhere else. You need to include code in your question that actually reproduces the problem you see. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As for headers, I don't see anywhere in what you've given us where you include headers in the first place.

Comment: @MattBurland I have updated the code above with the headers, I have also included the error I get in the console. You are right that it works in fiddle so I am not sure what else I can show here or what to try next?
I only get the error when I include the above record?

Comment: In you added code `js_data` is a string and you are using the `'` as a string delimiter. That is your problem because your string contains a `'` already. (and also you are missing the closing `'` anyway). If you need `js_data` to be a string, then you need to properly escape you string by using `\'`. i.e. `js_data = '[{"race_id":940558,"meeting_date":"11\/6\/2020","time":"16:00","course":"Gowran_Park","name":"Cap D\'antibes","back_price":8.4000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625,"probability":5,"qs_price":20.769999999999999573674358543939888477325439453125}]'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215753/discussion-between-midnightdatageek-and-matt-burland).

Comment: search google for json to csv npm.  there's a lot of implementations

Comment: @user120242 I did that already, thats how I managed to create the code in the first place but on that record above I get an error and I don't know why. I have tried searching for it but as Matt stated above, it works fine in fiddle so I am at a bit of a loss with it?

Comment: the syntax error you talk about implies you are using invalid javascript syntax.  The single quote issue Matt mentioned would trigger that.  Use backticks `js_data=\`[ {} ]\``

Comment: @user120242 The line of code that creates that is `var js_data = '<?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>';`
I don't know how to wrap that in backticks, can you suggest anything please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue here

[[php json_encode & jquery parseJSON single quote issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926354/php-json-encode-jquery-parsejson-single-quote-issue][1])

Changing this:
`var js_data = '<?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>';` to this
`var js_data = '<?php echo json_encode($obj, JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>';` solved the issue

Thanks all for your help